# How can I sign out other sessions via remote desktop?

Tags: windows, windows-8, remote-desktop

When I sign in via remote desktop sometimes the guest user is active and I need to wait for their permission to disconnect them before I can log in via remote desktop. However I do not want any user to be able to prevent me from signing in. How can I make it so when I sign in via remote desktop other sessions are automatically ended?

I am using windows 8

Answer (score 0):

You have to give more information about your infrastructure (Homenetwork? Active Directory and so on?

But the easiest way:

> qwinsta.exe /server: 'remotecomputername'
>
> e.g. qwinsta.exe /server: Computer123

You will get the list of users logged on the remote computer beside their login-ids.

> logoff 'user-id' /server: 'remotecomputername'
>
> e.g. logoff 2 /server: Computer123